# Two level filtering of list in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list `aList` of objects of class `A`. This `aList` is member of each element b of another list `bList`. Each element b is of class `B`. Structure of class `B` is as follows:

```
class B {
    String status;
    String name;
}
```

Structure of class `A` is as follows:

```
class A {
    List<B> bList;
    String status;
}
```

Now I would like to filter `aList` as follows:

Final list `aListResult` should contain object a only if a.status = "Active" as well as each "Active" a of aList should contain `bList` of only "Active" b objects i.e. if b will be in associated `bList` if and only if b.status == Active.

How would I achieve that in Java 8, I cannot figure out.

Comment: Do you wish your output list to contain only instances of A for which all the associated B instances are already active, or do you want to mutate the instances of A and remove references to non-active B instances?

Comment: Yes @Eran correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the output List to contain only active A instances for which all the associated B instances are active:

```
List<A> aList = ...;
List<A> aListResult = 
    aList.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getStatus().equals("Active"))
        .filter(a -> a.bList.stream().allMatch(b -> b.getStatus().equals("Active")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi Eran, nice answer, as always ;) Just a note on the usage of the `equals` method... Whenever you want to check equality against a constant ( `"Active"` in this case), it's better to check the constant against the variable, as in `"Active".equals(a.getStatus())`. This is to avoid a `NullPointerException` in case `a.getStatus()` returns `null`.